# CImg : what kind of values are required on this constructor?

Tags: cimg

In the documentation (http://cimg.eu/reference/structcimg__library_1_1CImg.html#a24f3b43daa4444b94a973c2c3fff82c5), you can read that the N°7 constructor requires an array of values to fill the image :

> values    =    Pointer to the input memory buffer.

You must know that I'm working with a RGB 2D image (so, a "normal"/"common" image).

Thus, I filled a vector (= more or less an array) with Nx3 values. N is the number of pixels, and the number "3" is because I use red, green and blue. I set the first value to 0, the 2nd to 0, the 3rd to 255 and these 3 operations are repeated N times. **That's why my vector, which is named `w`, looks like that : `{0, 0, 255 ; 0, 0, 255 ; etc.}`**

I wrote this constructor : `cimg_library::CImg<unsigned char>(&w[0], width, height, 2, 3);` to say that there are 3 channels, a depth of 2 (since I use 2D), and to give my values (width, height and pixels).

I should obtain a entirely blue image. But it's yellow. Why ? Did I badly used the vector ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike most formats which are stored *"band interleaved by pixel"*, i.e. RGBRGBRGB..., the data in a `CImg` are stored *"band-interleaved by plane"*, i.e. all the red components are first, then all the green components, then all the blue ones, so it looks like RRRGGGBBB. This is described [here](http://cimg.eu/reference/group__cimg__storage.html).

So, your code would need to be like this:

```
#include <vector>
#include "CImg.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace cimg_library;

int main()
{
    const int width=3;
    const int height=2;
    // 1. row - red, green, blue
    // 2. row - cyan, magenta, yellow

    // 6 pixels
    // Red plane first - red, green, blue, cyan, magenta, yellow
    // 255,0,0,0,255,255
    // Green plane next - red, green, blue, cyan, magenta, yellow
    // 0,255,0,255,0,255
    // Blue plane - red, green, blue, cyan, magenta, yellow
    // 0,0,255,255,255,0

    vector<unsigned char> w{
       255,0,0,0,255,255,
       0,255,0,255,0,255,
       0,0,255,255,255,0
    };

    CImg<unsigned char> image((unsigned char*)&w[0],width,height,1,3);
    image.save_pnm("result.pnm");
}
```

[image]

---

Or, if you simply want a solid blue image, the easiest way is probably to instantiate a simple 1x1 blue image using an initialiser for the one pixel, then to resize it:

```
    // Instantiate a 1x1 RGB image initialised to blue (last three values)
    CImg<unsigned char> blue(1,1,1,3,0,0,255);
    // Resize to larger image
    blue.resize(width,height);
```

---

Another method might be:

```
// Create RGB image and fill with Blue
CImg<unsigned char> image(width,height,1,3);
image.get_shared_channel(0).fill(0);
image.get_shared_channel(1).fill(0);
image.get_shared_channel(2).fill(255);
```

---

Another method might be:

```
CImg<unsigned char> image(256,256,1,3);

// for all pixels x,y in image
cimg_forXY(image,x,y) {
    image(x,y,0,0)=0;
    image(x,y,0,1)=0;
    image(x,y,0,2)=255;
}
```